# How can I programmatically create an endpoint and use it in my service instead of obtain it from the web.config?

Tags: wcf, azure, binding, endpoint

Basically I want to create this binding that will listen to azure service bus queue:

```
<services>
  <service name="myServiceName">
    <endpoint address="sb://****.servicebus.windows.net"
              listenUri="sb://****.servicebus.windows.net"
              binding="netMessagingBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="netMessagingBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="myConfiguration"
              name="myServiceEndpoint"
              contract="****" />
  </service>
```

I also need to know how I can use it in my service.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your servicehost file (.SVC) it can contain a reference to the factory class that generates your service file. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286.aspx

By providing your own factory you get an ability to override the generation of your service class via CreateServiceHost method.  That will give you more control as to how your service class is created.  You can inject your own URL's,l etc.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that, I know that method, I was looking for actual code examples / tutorials that implement the behavior if possible.